# How to update bower.json file to reflect changes when uninstalling a specific package(s)?

Tags: bower

How to update `bower.json` file to reflect changes when uninstalling a specific package(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-S` or `--save`:

> `-S, --save`              Remove uninstalled packages from the project's bower.json dependencies

You can check other options with `bower uninstall --help`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for more clearness and depending of @mziccard answer, to update the `bower.json` file with the uninstalled packages, use the next command in your terminal:

To uninstall one package..

```
$ bower uninstall <package_name> --save
```

And to uninstall multiple packages (3 for example), you can use the above command 2 more times, each time with its package_name or you can use the next one line command:

```
$ bower uninstall <package_name1> <package_name2> <package_name3> --save
```